# An arraylist to collect data from JSON array

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I spend too much time to read about list - collection in java and I can't find better solution than arraylist for collect data from JSON array and edit data if exist by key in mylist or if not exist just put model in mylist. I get stuck in two different projects on the same problem.

1. I can't edit int type in my arraylist throught arraylist for loop.
2. I can't find model in arraylist by key from JSON array and edit new parameter.

Can anybody tell me where I mix up?
Here is code for the first situation

```
if (kolekcija.get(Id).isEmpty()){
    kolekcija.get(Id).add(model);
} else {
    try {
        boolean isEmptyModel = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < kolekcija.get(Id).size(); i++){
            if (kolekcija.get(Id).get(i).getName.equals(model.Name)) {
                double dva = kolekcija . get (Id).get(i).getSum();
                kolekcija.get(Id).get(i).setSum(dva + 1.00);
            } else {
                isEmptyModel = true;
            }
        }
        if (isEmptyModel) {
            kolekcija.get(Id).get(i).add(model);
            isEmptyModel = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is code for second situation

```
// inside for loop to collect json object
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.setregister(reg);
boolean isEmptyModel = false;

if(listamodela.size() == 0){
    listamodela.add(model);
}

for(int i = 0; i < listamodela.size(); i++ ){
    if (listamodela.get(i).getregister().equals(reg)) {
        listamodela.get(i).addValueToList(value);
    } else {
        isEmptyModel = true;
    }
}

if(isEmptyModel){
    listamodela.add(model);
    isEmptyModel = false;
}
```

I have tried several solutions - contains, but I always have the same problem.

Comment: *I still not found good java editor for android.* Are you not using android studio?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question correctly, you are trying to save data by key, and if the key already exists in the collection, override that data/continue without overriding that data?

If this is the case, you can use a Map collection, instead of a list collection. 
the Map collection maps between key and value, and a key can not be repeated twice (Keys are stored in a Set collection, which means that duplicates are not allowed).

I would suggest reading about Map and HashMap.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm